# Store value into Database without using form

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

```
 var price = "900";
 var fee = "90";
 var price_tax = "180";
 var fee_tax = "9";
 var discount = '660';
 var grant_total = '1179'
```

I have these javascript variable in I want to save those into the table without using Input field how can i achieve this

```
$b_request = new Request;
$b_request->fill($request->all());

$b_request-price = $request->input('price');
$b_request->amt = $request->input('fee');
$b_request->samt = $request->input('price_tax');
$b_request->fee_tax = $request->input('fee_tax');
$b_request->discount = $request->input('discount');
$b_request->grant_total = $request->input('grant_total');
$b_request->save();
```

This does not work for me.

Also want ensure you I'm not passing any argument or parameter even I dont want to pass parameter in my routes

Comment: What does `$request` hold? How are you passing them in from the javascript ajax call?

Comment: To send javascript variables to the server, you either need a form or an ajax request.